# preg_replace_callback calling $this->method('\\1') at parameter 2

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

erm...i have a class, trying to make a template class, using preg_replace_callback, but i don't know how the parameter 2 write

```
class template {
   public function parse_template($newtpl, $cachetpl){
      ......
      $template = preg_replace("/\<\!\-\-\{(.+?)\}\-\-\>/s", "{\\1}", $template);
      $template = preg_replace_callback("/\{lang\s+(.+?)\}/is", $this->languagevar('\\1'), $template);
      ......
   }

   public function languagevar($param1){
      ......
      return $lang[$param1];
      ......
   }
}
```

how this work?

at my html(template) file, have something like this {lang hello}, and the parse_template found the {lang anything} it will convert using $this->languagevar('hello');

but i keep getting error at the

```
$template = preg_replace_callback("/\{lang\s+(.+?)\}/is", $this->languagevar('\\1'), $template);
```

the error message was

> preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '('\1')', to be a valid
>   callback

before i can do the callback using

```
preg_replace("/\{lang\s+(.+?)\}/ies", "\$this->languagevar('\\1')", $template);
```

but maybe current php version problem, it got error say that /e is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$template = preg_replace_callback("/\{lang\s+(.+?)\}/is", array($this, 'languagevar'), $template);
```

And the parameter passed to the callback function is an array of matched elements, so you have to change `languagevar` to below:

```
   public function languagevar($matches){
      /// ......
      return $lang[$matches[1]];
   }
```

Comment: erm...yesterday i tried this it work, but actually i got a lot of class method using the preg_replace('pattern/ies', '$this->callingmethod('\\1')', $template) to call the same way before, the only way i can do is all the method parameter1 set it $parameter[1] ?
any better way to avoid editing all method once again?except downgrade the php version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a valid [callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) as the second argument to `preg_replace_callback`. 
In your case that would be `array($this, 'languagevar')`.

Also note that you can't explicitly pass a captured group to the callback method like you're trying to do. The method will receive an array of *all* matched elements.

Comment: how do i parse the parameter into languagevar('parameter'), the parameter get from preg_replace (.+?)

Comment: @user3040842 Read the manual on `preg_replace_callback`. You can't pick what argument your callback will receive; it will be passed an array of *all elements matching the pattern*.